# C++ Sorting Filenames In A Directory

Tags: c++, linux, boost

I wanted to have some advice about the code I have.

I managed to get what I wanted done, but I do not think it is the "proper" way of doing it in the programmers' world.

Could you help me improve the code by any means and also if there are any better ways of doing this please share them as well.

I have files named in the format:

501.236.pcd

501.372.pcd

...

612.248.pcd etc.

I wanted to put the filenames in ascending order according to the filenames using C++.

This is the code I use:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main()
{
    vector <string> str,parsed_str;
    path p("./fake_pcd");
    string delimiter = ".";
    string token,parsed_filename;
    size_t pos = 0;
    int int_filename;
    vector <int> int_dir;

    //insert filenames in the directory to a string vector
    for (auto i = directory_iterator(p); i != directory_iterator(); i++)
    {
        if (!is_directory(i->path())) //we eliminate directories in a list
        {
        str.insert(str.end(),i->path().filename().string());
        }
        else
            continue;
    }

    //parse each string element in the vector, split from each delimiter 
    //add each token together and convert to integer
    //put inside a integer vector 
    parsed_str = str;
    for (std::vector<string>::iterator i=parsed_str.begin(); i != parsed_str.end(); ++i)
    {
        cout << *i << endl;
        while ((pos = i->find(delimiter)) != string::npos) {    
        token = i->substr(0,pos);
        parsed_filename += token;
        i->erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
    }

    int_filename = stoi(parsed_filename);
    int_dir.push_back(int_filename);

    parsed_filename = "";
    }

    cout << endl;

    parsed_str.clear();

    sort(int_dir.begin(), int_dir.end());

    //print the sorted integers
    for(vector<int>::const_iterator i=int_dir.begin(); i != int_dir.end(); i++) {
        cout << *i << endl;
    }

    //convert sorted integers to string and put them back into string vector
    for (auto &x : int_dir) {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << x;
        string y;
        ss >> y;
        parsed_str.push_back(y);
    }

    cout << endl;

    //change the strings so that they are like the original filenames  
    for(vector<string>::iterator i=parsed_str.begin(); i != parsed_str.end(); i++) {
        *i = i->substr(0,3) + "." + i->substr(3,3) + ".pcd";
        cout << *i << endl;
    }


}
```

This is the output, first part is in the order the directory_iterator gets it, the second part is the filenames sorted in integers, and the last part is where I change the integers back into strings in the original filename format.

```
612.948.pcd
612.247.pcd
501.567.pcd
501.346.pcd
501.236.pcd
512.567.pcd
613.008.pcd
502.567.pcd
612.237.pcd
612.248.pcd

501236
501346
501567
502567
512567
612237
612247
612248
612948
613008

501.236.pcd
501.346.pcd
501.567.pcd
502.567.pcd
512.567.pcd
612.237.pcd
612.247.pcd
612.248.pcd
612.948.pcd
613.008.pcd
```

Comment: For this example, it seems as if comparing the filenames directly as strings would work fine.

Comment: If you're looking for a code review, the place is [codereview.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a few hints from e.g. [Filtering folders in Boost Filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547921/filtering-folders-in-boost-filesystem/20595887#20595887) and in the interest of total overkill:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5c69a4e7d4e5949)</kbd>**  Using Boost (also [On Wandbox.org](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DkdACZkwvGpvB4Ga))

```
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <set>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

namespace {
    using Path = fs::path;

    struct Ranked {
        std::optional<int> rank;
        Path path;
        explicit operator bool() const { return rank.has_value(); }
        bool operator<(Ranked const& rhs) const { return rank < rhs.rank; }
    };

    static Ranked rank(Path const& p) {
        if (p.extension() == ".pcd") {
            auto stem = p.stem().native();

            std::string digits;
            using namespace boost::spirit::x3;
            if (phrase_parse(begin(stem), end(stem), +digit >> eoi, punct, digits))
                return { std::stoul(digits), p };
        }
        return { {}, p };
    }
}

int main() {
    using namespace boost::adaptors;

    auto dir = boost::make_iterator_range(fs::directory_iterator("."), {}) 
         | transformed(std::mem_fn(&fs::directory_entry::path))
         | transformed(rank)
         ;

    std::multiset<Ranked> index(begin(dir), end(dir));

    for (auto& [rank, path] : index) {
        std::cout << rank.value_or(-1) << "\t" << path << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
-1  "./main.cpp"
-1  "./a.out"
501008  "./501.008.pcd"
501236  "./501.236.pcd"
501237  "./501.237.pcd"
501247  "./501.247.pcd"
501248  "./501.248.pcd"
501346  "./501.346.pcd"
501567  "./501.567.pcd"
501948  "./501.948.pcd"
502008  "./502.008.pcd"
502236  "./502.236.pcd"
502237  "./502.237.pcd"
502247  "./502.247.pcd"
502248  "./502.248.pcd"
502346  "./502.346.pcd"
502567  "./502.567.pcd"
502948  "./502.948.pcd"
512008  "./512.008.pcd"
512236  "./512.236.pcd"
512237  "./512.237.pcd"
512247  "./512.247.pcd"
512248  "./512.248.pcd"
512346  "./512.346.pcd"
512567  "./512.567.pcd"
512948  "./512.948.pcd"
612008  "./612.008.pcd"
612236  "./612.236.pcd"
612237  "./612.237.pcd"
612247  "./612.247.pcd"
612248  "./612.248.pcd"
612346  "./612.346.pcd"
612567  "./612.567.pcd"
612948  "./612.948.pcd"
613008  "./613.008.pcd"
613236  "./613.236.pcd"
613237  "./613.237.pcd"
613247  "./613.247.pcd"
613248  "./613.248.pcd"
613346  "./613.346.pcd"
613567  "./613.567.pcd"
613948  "./613.948.pcd"
```

### BONUS: No-Boost Solution

As the filesystem library has been standardized and using Rangev3:

**<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ICpl3RMncJHuqDMG)</kbd>**

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <optional>
#include <range/v3/action/remove_if.hpp>
#include <range/v3/range/conversion.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/filter.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/subrange.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/transform.hpp>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

namespace {
    using namespace ranges;

    using Ranked = std::pair<std::optional<int>, fs::path>;
    bool has_rank(Ranked const& v) { return v.first.has_value(); }

    static Ranked ranking(fs::path const& p) {
        if (p.extension() == ".pcd") {
            auto stem = p.stem().native();
            auto non_digit = [](uint8_t ch) { return !std::isdigit(ch); };
            stem |= actions::remove_if(non_digit);
            return { std::stoul(stem), p };
        }
        return { {}, p };
    }
}

int main() {
    using It = fs::directory_iterator;

    for (auto&& [rank, path] : subrange(It("."), It())
            | views::transform(std::mem_fn(&fs::directory_entry::path))
            | views::transform(ranking)
            | views::filter(has_rank)
            | to<std::multimap>())
    {
        std::cout << rank.value_or(-1) << "\t" << path << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints e.g.

```
501236  "./501.236.pcd"
501346  "./501.346.pcd"
501567  "./501.567.pcd"
502567  "./502.567.pcd"
```